# Reading expressions for postfixed notation calculator by using scanf

Tags: c, postfix-notation

I have a problem with the input for a postfixed notation calculator in C.
My teacher asked me to use scanf("%s",token) to get the input. To stop reading tokens, I check if the value returned by scanf is EOF. It works if I use input redirection when testing, but if I write the expression on the Windows cmd I fall into an endless loop. How can I stop scanf when I simply press enter without entering a string?
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "stack.h"

int main(){
    int a,b,t,stop;
    char token[10],c;
    do{
        stop = scanf("%s",token);
        if (stop == EOF){
            break;
        }
        if (isdigit(token[0])){
           t = atoi(token);
           push(t);     
        }else{
           a = top();   
           pop();       
           b = top();
           pop();
           c = token[0];
           switch(c){
            case '+': t = a + b;
                         break;
            case '-': t = a - b;
                         break;
            case '*': t = a * b;
                         break;
            case '/': t = a / b;
                         break;
           }
           push(t);
        }
   } while(1);
   printf("Result: %d\n",top());
}
```

The problem is in the if block after the stop variable inizialisation, I think. Sorry for my English, I'm an Italian student, I tried to be as neat as I can.

Comment: `ctrl+z` enter for `EOF`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY or `ctrl+d`

Comment: @iharob his system is `Windows cmd` (his write)

Comment: Maybe it's better to have some reserved word, for example "STOP", so when you enter that word you stop reading input. That's common approach in command line applications that read from STDIN.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks, that's what I was looking for. Only one more question: to stop the program, I had to type ctrl+z twice. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Are you only input ctrl+z?

Comment: My input:
"3 5 +(crtl+z)
(ctrl+z)"

Answer (score 0):

"How can I stop scanf when I simply press enter without entering a string?"

Using `scanf()` to read `'\n'` (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) is challenging.  `fgets()` or `fgetc()` is a better approach.  But the following shows how to nearly do it with `scanf()`.

The `%s` in `scanf("%s",token);` first consumes leading white-space including `'\n'`.  Code must first detect any potential `'\n'` before calling `scanf("%s",token);`.

```
 char ws[2];

 // Consume white-space, but not \n
 scanf("%*[ \f\r\t\v]");  // Depending on locale, this may not be a complete list
 if (1 == scanf("%1[\n]", ws) {
   break;
 }

 stop = scanf("%s",token);
 if (stop == EOF){
   break;
 }
```

---

A cleaner way to do this.

```
 int ch;
 while (isspace(ch = fgetc(stdin)) && ch != '\n');
 if (ch == '\n') {
   break;
 }
 ungetc(ch, stdin);

 stop = scanf("%s",token);
 if (stop == EOF){
   break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Only one more question: to stop the program, I had to type ctrl+z
>   twice. Can you tell me why?

Usually the C standard input in line buffered text mode is implemented by calling a system specific function which reads a line and returns the number of characters in it (including the newline character); when the number 0 is returned, this is considered EOF. Now, when you enter "3 5 +(crtl+z)(ctrl+z)", the first Ctrl-Z ends the input line and causes the reading function to return 5, but this does not indicate EOF to the standard input functions; only after the second Ctrl-Z ist pressed without intervening input, 0 is returned and recognized as EOF.